# how to create ramfs or tmpfs that won't be existed after reboot?

Tags: linux, filesystems, tmpfs

For security reasons I want to setup a temporary directory or partition that will be removed if the system rebooted or in case of power outage.

I tried to create a tmpfs but the files where there after reboot, is there any other option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search leads to this page: https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux

And this command:

`mount -t [TYPE] -o size=[SIZE] [FSTYPE] [MOUNTPOINT]`

Example from the link:

`mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk`

If you did this right, your tmpfs partition should **not** exist after rebooting.

Comment: It's weird because I did tried a few guides and the files were still in the tmp directory after reboot, anyway it's working now, thank you !

Comment: That's really weird. Also, in the future please add to your original post any commands you have already tried, e.g. "I tried mount -o foo /dev/bar", which will help others answer your question.